# can i integrate a wordpress blog into a facebook application

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, blogs

i was wondering whether i can incorporate wordpress blog into a facebook application so that i specify the Canvas URL to point to the blog's url.i haven't really tried it out,was just thinking about it.

2.if the answer is no,are there any other blogging platforms that allow this e.g blogger and the likes.thanks

Comment: @webarto the wordpress guys do not have an issue about that rinfringing on their laws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put yes although there are some things you need to be made aware of:

- Facebook Applications now require a Secure URL, that is a URL that is accessed via HTTPS:// not the standard HTTP://
- Facebook does not allow the use of custom Javascript and only allows you to implement the Facebook javascript SDK
- Styling can be a bit of a pain. If your placing the application into a page then remember there are sizing (width) issues that you have to bear in mind.

Hope this helps out a little bit. If not here's an article I followed some time ago relating to your questions: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-fall-2012/

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Apps are simply just iFrames to another URL anywhere on the internet. You can put anything you want inside of this iFrame (within [Platform Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy) of course) and it will work. It won't bring you any additional functionality though, for that you'll need to start integrating [plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins) and [APIs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api).